# NXP NTAG 424: write command returns 917E: "Length Error"". Why?

Tags: nfc, iso, apdu

I have started working with the [NXP NTAG 424 TT](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/ntag/ntag-for-tags-labels/ntag-424-dna-424-dna-tagtamper-advanced-security-and-privacy-for-trusted-iot-applications:NTAG424DNA) chip together with nfcpy and an Identive SCL3711 Reader/Writer. I can successfully send and receive APDU commands, securely authenticate myself and send and receive commands in encrypted communication mode.

However I can't read or write Data to the chip, and I don't know why. Here is what I do (mostly taken from the [NXP application](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf) note Page 24):

1. I send the command "ISO Select NDEF application using DF Name"
   `00A404C07D276000085010100`
2. Then I perform the secure authentication protocol via `AuthenticatEV2First` with key 0x00
3. I try to write some data as follows:

```
cmd_header = 02000000040000
cmd_data = 00D1FF00 (before padding)
cmd_data = 00D1FF00800000000000000000000000 (after padding)
The complete command which I send looks like this:
cla cmd P1&2| Lc |ISO Header      | encrypted Data                                 |LE
90 8D 00 00   1F  02 000000 040000 6688A4D75482FC972C2447A1A20F0AC9C073C1CF506B2BD3 00
```

However the chip only responds with `917E`: "Length Error"" which translates to "Command size not allowed"
What am I doing wrong? It can't be the encryption, I tested that with various other commands (getTTStatus, SetConfiguration) and these all worked fine. I quadruple checked the header. Did I perhaps fail to select the correct File, or did I miss some other steps? Also what does "Command size not allowed" mean? This error is pretty cryptic to me (which is funny when working with encrypted chips :D).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of "encrypted data" field in your case is 24 bytes, whereas the length which you have mentioned in ISO Header is "040000" i.e. 4 bytes.
Your encrypted data length should match with the length of data you are writing.
In your case there is mismatch in both lengths and resulting in error.

Hope the information is clear.
Cheers!